# Cloud firestore: How to create and update a nested array with map object

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create/update a set of data in the cloud firestore in that is stored in a nested array method.

[image]
I want to define the nested array to be in a `Map<String, dynamic>` method like this.

Comment: Please follow below questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67838039/flutter-firestore-update-array-of-object-by-param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to create instance of categories model then change the value according to your requirement

***for ex:***

```
 Categories c =  categories; // here assign your exiting data of categories
     c.copyWith(flavor : ["hello","world"]);

          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('user')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
          .collection('todos')
          .doc(map["collectionId"])
          .update(FieldValue.arrayUnion(c)))
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example of how to write a copyWith function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372580/what-is-copywith-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-flutter-and-what-are-its-use-cases @NitinGopal please refer it